# How to access dask dataframe index value in map_paritions?

Tags: pandas, dask

I am trying to use dask dataframe map_partition to apply a function which access the value in the dataframe index, rowise and create a new column.

Below is the code I tried.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index = ["row0" , "row1","row2","row3","row4"])
df
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

res = ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: df.assign(index_copy= str(df.index)),meta={'index_copy': 'U' })
res.compute()
```

I am expecting df.index to be the value in the row index, not the entire partition index which it seems to refer to. From the doc [here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions), this work well for columns but not the index.

Answer (score 2):

what you want to do is this

```
df.index = ['row'+str(x) for x in df.index]
```

and for that first create your pandas dataframe and then run this code after you will have your expected result.
let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This does the trick. `import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index = ["row0" , "row1","row2","row3","row4"])
df
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

res = ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: df.assign(index_copy= [ e for e in df.index] ),meta={'index_copy': 'U' })
res.compute()`. Note though that the original df already has ` ["row0" , "row1","row2","row3","row4"]` as index.